# After upgrade on Ubuntu 19.10 internet connection exclusively works when connected to VPN

Tags: internet, vpn, 19.10

It's a bit odd, but since the upgrade to 19.10 I can only access the internet through browser and email *after* I connected to my VPN. Before it is not possible. Any pointers?

edit:

```
$ ip link;ip route
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp57s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:fa:5b:68:a8:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp58s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:56:80:e6:5d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: anbox0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:cd:bf:bf:11:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev anbox0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.126 metric 600 
192.168.250.0/24 dev anbox0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.250.1
```

And after connecting to the VPN:

```
$ ip link;ip route
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp57s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:fa:5b:68:a8:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp58s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:56:80:e6:5d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: anbox0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:cd:bf:bf:11:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 100
    link/none 
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.21 
37.120.217.203 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev anbox0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp58s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.126 metric 600 
192.168.250.0/24 dev anbox0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.250.1
```

edit2:

```
$ vim resolv.conf
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search lan
```

edit3:

`$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNS Domain: lan
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test`

Link 14 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 103.86.96.96
         DNS Servers: 103.86.99.99
                      103.86.96.96
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 3 (wlp58s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

Link 2 (enp57s0f1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Comment: How are you connected before you start the VPN? `ip link;ip route`

Comment: @waltinator I added the output

Comment: what VPN are you using? what is the output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: I'm using NordVPN @JoKeR. The output

`$ vim resolv.conf
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search lan
~
~
`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have NordVPN servers listed, they are:

```
nameserver 103.86.96.100
nameserver 103.86.99.100
```

You can add them manually instead of current *nameserver* or replace it with Google servers

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save and close and reload the network manager. Or reboot the system NordVPN should replace it with their *nameservers* at startup.

Also you can remove *nordvpn* package if it won't work then reboot and install it back, it should do the trick.

P.S.

Also make sure you didn't activate NordVPN DNS option manually.

check `nordvpn settings` in terminal if DNS enabled then turn it off `nordvpn set dns off`

Comment: if I run `systemd-resolve --status` the nordvpn nameservers you named are listed. I added the output to the original request.

Comment: do you use killswitch? if yes turn it off `nordvpn set killswitch off` then reboot and check the connection.